# Partitioning graph and cutting size using KL algorithm

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have the following graph:

[image]

I'm trying to partition this graph into two sets of 100 nodes each using the KL algorithm.

I've attempted to do this using MATLAB using the following two resources as guides:

- [Resource 1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37082-kl-transform-karhunen-loeve-theorem)
- [Resource 2](https://www.scribd.com/document/170614128/Matlab-Code-for-Kl-Algo)

My attempt:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
I=imread('graph.jpg');
I=im2double(I);
m=1;
for i=1:8:256
    for j=1:8:256
        for x=0:7
            for y=0:7
            img(x+1,y+1)=I(i+x,j+y);
            end
        end
            k=0;
            for l=1:8
                img_expect{k+1}=img(:,l)*img(:,l)';
                k=k+1;
            end
            imgexp=zeros(8:8);
            for l=1:8
                imgexp=imgexp+(1/8)*img_expect{l};%expectation of E[xx']
            end
            img_mean=zeros(8,1);
            for l=1:8
                img_mean=img_mean+(1/8)*img(:,l);
            end
            img_mean_trans=img_mean*img_mean';
            img_covariance=imgexp - img_mean_trans;
            [v{m},d{m}]=eig(img_covariance);
            temp=v{m};
             m=m+1;
            for l=1:8
                v{m-1}(:,l)=temp(:,8-(l-1));
            end
             for l=1:8
           trans_img1(:,l)=v{m-1}*img(:,l);
             end
           for x=0:7
               for  y=0:7
                   transformed_img(i+x,j+y)=trans_img1(x+1,y+1);
               end
           end
mask=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ];
  trans_img=trans_img1.*mask;
           for l=1:8
           inv_trans_img(:,l)=v{m-1}'*trans_img(:,l);
           end
            for x=0:7
               for  y=0:7
                  inv_transformed_img(i+x,j+y)=inv_trans_img(x+1,y+1);
               end
           end
  
           
        end
end
imshow(transformed_img);
figure
imshow(inv_transformed_img);
```

However, the code above and in the resources linked involve matrices and I'm not sure how I can relate that to my graph?

How can I partition this graph into two sets of 100 nodes and cut size value at each node exchange?

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What do you mean by the "code above and in the resources linked involve matrices and I'm not sure how I can relate that to my graph"? To generate that graph you already had data in matrices but, even if you didn't, images ARE matrices. In fact, basically everything is a matrix in matlab.

Comment: [Resource 1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37082-kl-transform-karhunen-loeve-theorem) is for Karhunen-Loève but [Resource 2](https://www.scribd.com/document/170614128/Matlab-Code-for-Kl-Algo) is for Kernighan-Lin. These are different KLs. Graph partitioning is done with Kernighan-Lin but your code block is from the Karhunen-Loève link.